# How to center all list's elements to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am going to add dynamically elements to my block of ul. 
I would like to center all list's elements to parent div(brown boder).
For example, 
if the resolution of the browser allows you to set two blocks in one row, I would like to center this row in relation to parent div.

I would be very graftefully.

[Link to demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5o1k1mfe/)

**myCode:**

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

   var tab = [2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15];

    $(document).ready(function(){



    $('#godziny').on('click', '.godzina', function(){
        //alert(this.attr('class'));
        $('.yb').removeClass('yb');
        $(this).addClass('yb');
    });

    $('#getElements').click(function() {
         for(i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i) {
        alert(tab[i]);
        setTimeout(function(i){
           $('#godziny').append('<li class="godzina">' + tab[i] + '</li>');             
        }, i*50);
         }

        });
   });
</script>
<style>
#spisSalonow {
    margin: 0 auto;
}   

#spisSalonow > div {
   padding-top: 15px;
   color:red;
}

#wybor_terminu  {
    border: 1px solid brown;
}

#wybor_terminu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#wybor_terminu ul li {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    border: 0.2em solid green;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    /*margin:auto;*/
    /*
       opacity: 0.4;
       filter: alpha(opacity=40);
   */
}

.yb {
   background: yellow;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="button" value="get Elements" id="getElements"/>
        <section id="content">
            <div class="full">
                <BR/>
                <div id="wybor_terminu" class="center border" style="width: 70%; position: relative;">
                    <div style="text-align: center"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-05-24.png" alt="Left Arrow" />  <span id="day"> ANY DAY </span> <img src="http://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-06-24.png" alt="Right Arrow" /></div>
                    <ul id="godziny" style="margin-top: 25px;">

                    </ul>
                </div>
        </section>
</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines:

**CSS**

```
#wybor_terminu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*NEW*/
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#wybor_terminu ul li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  border: 0.2em solid green;
  /*float: left; You don't need this line*/
  cursor: pointer;
  /*NEW*/
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
```

}

**EDIT**

This is only a quick solution with **bootstrap** maybe it could help you a little bit. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4kk8bav/2/)

**jQuery**

In this line I added bootstrap classes:

```
$('#godziny').append('<li class="godzina col-sm-12 col-md-6">' + tab[i] + '</li>');
```

This code center your boxes (is not the best solution, but it works):

```
countBoxes = $('#godziny').width() / 200;
alignBoxes = ($('#godziny').width()-(200*parseInt(countBoxes)))/2;

if(countBoxes >= 2.65){
   $('#godziny').css('margin-left', alignBoxes);
} else{
   $('#godziny').css('margin-left', 0);   
}
```

If you change the resolution of your screen, click the button to center your boxes again.

Comment: NO, NOW all elements in a single vertical line for all resolution of browser. You resolution allows you display to two columns of li's elements, so i would like to center that two columnt to parent div

Comment: Please let me know, if this is what you mean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS flexbox to achieve this. Here is a link to a complete guide on how to use flexbox. I hope this helps.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/